# Make comment flags link to the comment

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flags, comment-flags

When reviewing comment flags on large posts with lots of discussion (generally on metas), sometimes you need to view a comment in context. With the current system, this involves scrolling up and down, unrolling all the comment threads, and then searching for it. Annoying, especially when the flag overlay takes up half the page. There's no way to directly "jump" to a comment.

What I propose is this:

[image]

Make the timestamp in the flag overlay into a comment link.

Comment: I thought they did, or is that just in the flagging overview, not on the question page when a flag exists?

Comment: @BenBrocka: This is on the flag overlay on a question page. The semi-transparent thingy.

Comment: You mean someone actually uses that thing? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The overlay? I'm no fan of it, but there are times when I realize its use. If you're talking about comment flags, then you'd be surprised...